# Postgresql row gets hidden after update, can't select it

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm having this problem where my rows are being "hidden" (or SELECT * doesn't retrieve them) after updating.

I've tried with CLI and with a GUI (DBeaver) but the result it's the same, here is an example:

```
select * from users limit 4;
 id |             email              |    password     |  status  |  role  |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+--------------------------------+-----------------+----------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  8 | Brad.Bailey@gmail.com          | qYHsmrKWaiaiZxI | disabled | seller | 2019-09-06 21:43:08.043-03 | 2019-08-13 16:04:25.233-03
  9 | Marcelino_Prohaska97@gmail.com | sUMuOM_gXCPxz19 | disabled | seller | 2019-06-14 15:39:45.447-03 | 2019-06-25 12:54:01.023-03
 10 | Gino_Blick@gmail.com           | iOkZQhc7JSsQcpY | disabled | seller | 2020-02-13 13:39:16.26-03  | 2019-12-18 17:02:37.938-03
 11 | Tiffany.Schuster16@yahoo.com   | Bw2OhPUtIRcWxZF | active   | seller | 2018-07-30 08:01:29.942-03 | 2019-09-03 10:50:40.314-03
(4 rows)
```

Then

```
update users set email = 'test@test.com' where id = 8;
UPDATE 1
```

And then, this happens:

```
select * from users limit 4;
 id |             email              |    password     |  status  |  role  |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+--------------------------------+-----------------+----------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  9 | Marcelino_Prohaska97@gmail.com | sUMuOM_gXCPxz19 | disabled | seller | 2019-06-14 15:39:45.447-03 | 2019-06-25 12:54:01.023-03
 10 | Gino_Blick@gmail.com           | iOkZQhc7JSsQcpY | disabled | seller | 2020-02-13 13:39:16.26-03  | 2019-12-18 17:02:37.938-03
 11 | Tiffany.Schuster16@yahoo.com   | Bw2OhPUtIRcWxZF | active   | seller | 2018-07-30 08:01:29.942-03 | 2019-09-03 10:50:40.314-03
 12 | Brody_Pollich@yahoo.com        | ZlFy3kEUSrmxHAa | disabled | seller | 2018-07-06 13:18:29.936-03 | 2019-08-03 21:46:22.296-03
(4 rows)
```

The thing is, the row still exists, but it is not shown by SELECT *

```
select * from users where id = 8 limit 10;
 id |     email     |    password     |  status  |  role  |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+---------------+-----------------+----------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  8 | test@test.com | qYHsmrKWaiaiZxI | disabled | seller | 2019-09-06 21:43:08.043-03 | 2019-08-13 16:04:25.233-03
(1 row)
```

Here is the structure of my table (code by Dbeaver) and the version of my Postgresql:

```
CREATE TABLE public.users (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "password" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    status varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "role" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamptz NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamptz NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT users_email_unique UNIQUE (email),
    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

SELECT version();
                                                             version                                                             
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
-------------------------------------
PostgreSQL 12.3 (Ubuntu 12.3-1.pgdg18.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is what happens when you use LIMIT without ORDER BY. The result is unpredictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `limit` and apply `order by`:

```
select * from users order by id;
```

Is `ID = 8` back?

Documentation says:

> Because the order of the rows in the database table is unspecified, when you use the LIMIT clause, you should always use the ORDER BY clause to control the row order. If you don’t do so, you will get a result set whose rows are in an unspecified order.

which means that you saw record with `ID = 8` *by accident*; no guarantee you'll get it again just with the `limit` clause.

Comment: Well you're totally right, I must've missed that part of the documentation. I kept getting the `ID = 8` consistently again and again, so I didn't think it was _an accident_. Anyway, it worked perfectly when using order by, thanks!